# Why am I seeing MailSlot Browse messages on unrouted ports of my Linux box?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, windows

I have a Linux box (Debian squeeze) with several NICs. The ones of interest are:

- eth3 - my main link to the network (dhcp on 10.20.30.0/24)
- eth0 - the first connection to my test network (static: 192.168.1.2)
- eth4 - the second connection to my test network (static: 192.168.1.1)

My routing table looks like this:

```
$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.20.30.0      *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth3
default         10.20.30.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth3
```

I have the 2 test net ports connected to each other with a crossover cable and an instance of wireshark running on each port. Every once in a while, I'll see a packet like the following show up.
[image: MailSlot Packet]

Who could be doing this, and how do I convince them to stop? I do have Samba running on the machine (for a cifs mount) but don't see why it would be sending packets out to unrouted ports. I had a Windows VM running in VMWare Client and thought that might be causing it, but it still happens without it.

What I want is totally silent interfaces so I can run some tests with Scapy over them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like AsustekC_54:85:eb is sending a broadcast which is your eth0 interface. There is probably a service on the server broadcasting this on all interfaces.